# User always being redirected to Home page instead of requested page

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, angular-auth-oidc-client

In my Angular project, users are being authenticated through OIDC provider using the library [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client). So, when user is not authenticated or session expired and requests a page like https://localhost:4202/account, user is being redirected to OIDC login page and after successful login, user is always being redirected to home page instead of requested page

**To Reproduce:**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Replace Auth configuration with your own config
2. Run the project with

```
npm run start
```

3. Go to https://localhost:4202/account. It will redirect to OIDC login page then after successful login it redirects user to https://localhost:4202 instead of https://localhost:4202/account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not storing `redirectedUrl` in storage and retrieve it back after successful navigation. The library already has `AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard` which can be used in custom guards. See the source code in [Github](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/9a4c268cd603409c41ac88d4da02d1892325b2cc/projects/angular-auth-oidc-client/src/lib/auto-login/auto-login-partial-routes.guard.ts#L33) and sample admin guard that extends  `AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard` below. This will make sure user redirects back to original URL

**Admin Auth Guard**:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AdminUserAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private autoLoginPartialRoutesGuard: AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard
    ) {}


    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        if (this.autoLoginPartialRoutesGuard.canActivate(route, state) && this.currentUserState.hasSysAdminRole) {
            return true;
        }
        if (this.autoLoginPartialRoutesGuard.canActivate(route, state) && !this.currentUserState.hasSysAdminRole) {
            this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of the lib are you using?

Comment: Can you please share how you're redirecting to a requested path?
I'm also facing the same error where being logged in I'm opening the angular page in a new tab giving me the same outcome always getting redirected to home.

Answer (score 0):

in auth service:

```
this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin().then(
        (isLoggedIn) => {

          if (isLoggedIn) {
            this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
            resolveFn();
          } else {
            this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow(window.location.pathname);
            rejectFn();
          }
        })
```

init code:

```
initLogin() {
   this.oauthService.events
    .pipe(
      filter((e: any) => e.type === 'token_received'))
    .subscribe(({ type }) => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(decodeURIComponent(this.oauthService.state));
    });
 }
```